# Django Models - Column save based on primary key when post

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

This is my model.py

```
class AppointmentMaster(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_key = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=AppointmentMaster)
def generate_AppointmentMaster_unique_key(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

   post_save.disconnect(generate_AppointmentMaster_unique_key, sender=MenstrualHistory)
   instance.menstrual_history_n_key = "USER-{}".format(instance.id)
   instance.save()
   post_save.connect(generate_AppointmentMaster_unique_key, sender=AppointmentMaster)
```

and i'm using **viewsets.ModelViewSet** for post details.I want to save user_key automatically when create a new row from post api.

I want output like

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "user_key":"USER-1",
   "phone_number":"90000000",
   "email":"abc@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `.save()` method in `Model` that will automatically perform this action when ever you `update` or `create` an object.

```
class AppointmentMaster(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_key = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_key = f"USER-{self.id}"
        super(AppointmentMaster, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I got output like {self.id} is None (USER-None)

Comment: ```AppointmentMaster.objects.create(phone_number="your-phonenumber", email="your-email")``` , If your query is similar to this than it shouldn't give you the None output.
OR
the Python3x has f-string feature. if you are using python below 3 than try ```"USER-"+str(self.id)```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use viewsets much. If you can steer away from them with your app this might work. I'd also recommend using the pk which already comes with each model instance instead of your 'id' field, which I assume serves a similar purpose.

yourapp.views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['POST'])
def yourView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        appt = AppointmentMaster()
        appt.user_key = data.get('user_key')
        appt.phone_number = data.get("phone_number")
        appt.email = data.get("email")
        appt.save()
        return Response('id':appt.id, 'user_key':appt.user_key, 'phone_number':appt.phone_number, 'email':appt.email)
```

You may need to include some additional error checking to ensure the instance was properly saved and possibly query it from the db in order for the 'appt.id' to work properly in the response. that would entail you adding:

```
...
appt.save()
newAppt = AppointmentMaster.objects.get(user_key=data.get('user_key'))
```

and then replacing all response parameters with 'newAppt' instead of 'appt'. Hope this helped and I understood your question :D